# Create a file with the received name

Tags: java

I created a function to create Classroom. Now I want to save the information of the created class in a file with the name of the same class, for example:

i want to create a class with a math name that stores the information of the classroom, including the classroom capacity and classroom's name, in a txt file.

```
public void  createclass(String name,int capacity){
     System.out.println("class created !!!");

     try {
        File [The name we chose for the class]= new File("E:\\[The name we chose for the class].txt");
        String str ="class "+name+" "+"with "+capacity+" capacity"+"was created";
        FileWriter fileWriter=new FileWriter([our file name]);
        fileWriter.write(str);
        fileWriter.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
 }
```

Comment: [You already asked this question an hour ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70479219/create-a-file-with-the-received-name).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of the class like this:

```
this.getClass().getSimpleName()
```

Hope that was the problem.